# pygame - How to group sprites

Tags: python, pygame

Having a real struggle getting this sorted. Had look at some other answers, and I get an error saying that I have too many arguments.

Class containing the objects I want to add.

```
class Digimon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,age,weight,strength,defence,speed,intelligence, image):
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.strength = strength
        self.defence = defence
        self.speed = speed
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.image = image
```

Have tried to do:

```
class Digimon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,age,weight,strength,defence,speed,intelligence, image)
    self.age = age  
    self.weight = weight    
    self.strength = strength 
    self.defence = defence  
    self.speed = speed  
    self.intelligence = intelligence 
    self.image = image
```

but I error regarding the amount of arguments. (1 given, 7 needed).

```
Player = Digimon(0,2,0,0,0,0, [pygame.image.load("images/koro_1.png"), pygame.image.load("images/koro_2.png"), pygame.image.load("images/koro_3.png") ] )
```

This is in example of an object which I want to group together. From this, I'll be able to add keyboard events which affect all the objects grouped.

Any help would be fantastic :D

edit: full code: http://pastebin.com/uPWEM8bD

Comment: _"but I error regarding the amount of arguments."_ What's the actual error? Also, can you fix your second code block? All of your assignments are on one line.

Comment: http://puu.sh/7jUK8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,age,weight,strength,defence,speed,intelligence, image)
```

The base Sprite class has no need for your age/weight/etc variables. Just pass in `self`:

```
pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```

Comment: Do I pass the self.arguments in the 

    def __init__(self,age,weight,strength,defence,speed,intelligence,image) ?

Comment: Yes, you should still pass arguments on your `Player =` line.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have 8 arguments (7 number variables and an image) in the definition but when you call it you pass 7 (6 ints and a list of images).</strike>

Comment: 7 number variables? I count six: age, weight, strength, defence, speed, intelligence. `self` doesn't count because it's passed implicitly without you having to supply anything.

Comment: Yeah I see that now, misread it the first time thanks for pointing that out.